# How to connect to multiple db in a php file?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I am using DBAL with Doctrine to make a connection in Symfony 3 to a database. What I'd like to do is to have all my queries in a PHP file, not in a controller.

In a controller I can use this:

```
$conn = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.database2_connection');
```

to get a connection, but in a simple PHP I cannot.

So, I don't know how to call multiple connections without using the `EntityManager`object because I'm not working with an Entity class.

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "simple PHP file", I don't think that Symfony (2 and 3) methodology allows the usage of "simple PHP files".

Comment: I mean a php class not declare as a controller @FabriceKabongo

Comment: Take a look at service configuration and dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PDO, every connection is treated as an object, and you can have an arbitrary number of them simultaneously. [Check out the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to need to master the next things:

1. You need to check how to work with multiple databases (I guess that's what you mean by many connections) [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).
2. Also, you need to see how to [create custom repositories.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)
3. You will need to use [DQL (doctrine query language)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) to do your own queries.
4. And the last point is that you need to get used with [Symfony's dependency injection.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html)

Feel free to skip everything you already know. I can't detail everything here because your question is quite vague. So this answer will guide on how to find your solution or at least focus your question.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony Allows you to connect multiple databases. You need to do a bt workout to achieve this.

Step#1

Add parameters to `parameters.yml` file. The second database connection could be added using the following parameters:

```
Parameters:

# First database

  database_host: 127.0.0.1   
  database_port: null   
  database_name: qmsfumgabd  
  database_user: qmsfumgabd 
  database_password: xxx9bxxMxx

# Second database

  database2_host: 127.0.0.1 
  database2_port: null 
  database2_name: huscqxzwaw
  database2_user: huscqxzwaw
  database2_password: dxxxFXxxxB
```

Step#2

The next step is to get these credentials in the `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:

  # Configure the abstraction layer

  dbal:

      # Set the default connection to default

      default_connection: default

      connections:

          default:

                driver: pdo_mysql

                host: '%database_host%'

                port: '%database_port%'

                dbname: '%database_name%'

                user: '%database_user%'

                password:  '%database_password%'

                charset: UTF8

         database2:

               driver:    pdo_mysql

               host:      '%database2_host%'

               port:      '%database2_port%'

               dbname:    '%database2_name%'

               user:      '%database2_user%'

               password:  '%database2_password%'

               charset:   UTF8
```

Step#3

Finally, specify the mapping of each bundle in the project:

```
# Configure the ORM

  orm:

      default_entity_manager: default

      entity_managers:

          # Register which bundle should use which connection

          default:

              connection: default

              mappings:

                  AppBundle:  ~

                  DemoBundle: ~

          database2:

              connection: database2

              mappings:

                  CloudwaysBundle: ~
```

Step#4

Now for calling any of the entity manager use connection names simply:

```
class UserController extends Controller

{

   public function indexAction()

   {

       // All 3 return the "default" entity manager

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');

       $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');



       // Both of these return the "database2" entity manager

       $anotherEm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('database2');

       $anotherEm = $this->get('doctrine.orm.database2_entity_manager');

   }

}
```

You can also take help from symfony's documentation for [multiple databases](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).